# Type Checking for collection in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, collections

I have tried the following:

```
  portfolioList: MatTableDataSource<Portfolio>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.backend.getStatement().subscribe(
      list => {
        if(list as Portfolio[])
        this.portfolioList = new MatTableDataSource(list);
      }
    );
  }
```

`Portfolio` is an interface.

I'm getting an error :

```
Error: src/app/admin/statement/statement.component.ts:28:53 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Portfolio[]'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Portfolio[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.

28         this.portfolioList = new MatTableDataSource(list);
```

Why am I getting the error and how do I fix it?
I have tried to work with `typeof()` and `instanceof` in place of `as`. But I wasnt able to fix the error.

Comment: I also get the message: `'Portfolio' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Comment: `as Portfolio[]` is a type cast, which doesn't make too much sense in the `if` condition.

Comment: Is this angular-specific? If so you might want to tag it as such; if not, you might want to [edit] the code so that it's a self-contained [mre] which demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE.  If you decide to do this and want me to take another look, leave a comment mentioning @jcalz to notify me. Good luck!

Comment: Exactly what type does this.backend.getStatement() return? Try getting that typed properly first.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check first that `list` is an array and that all the items in the array are of type `Portfolio`.

```
if (Array.isArray(list) && list.every(item => item instanceof Portfolio)) {
  this.portfolioList = new MatTableDataSource(list);
}
```

Comment: For the `typeof item === 'Portfolio'` part, I get the following error.

`Error: src/app/admin/statement/statement.component.ts:28:55 - error TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | 
"function"' and '"Portfolio"' have no overlap.

28         if (Array.isArray(list) && list.every(item => typeof item == 'Portfolio'))`

Comment: I've edited my answer to the `instanceof` operation instead of `typeof` since typeof can only determine the types listed in the error you've got (string, number, bigint...). To check if a value is an instance of a given constructor function or class you should use `instanceof`